# Selecting Pandas Dataframe Rows where Index Label is in One of Two Lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with index labels

```
     one   two three

A    ...   ...   ... 
B    ...   ...   ... 
C    ...   ...   ... 
D    ...   ...   ... 
E    ...   ...   ... 
F    ...   ...   ...
```

I want to subset the dataframe based on whether the row index label is in one list or another.  The lists are exclusive and will not contain the same elements.

I can do this with one list but seemingly not two.

so if I have `list_A = ['A, B, F']`  and `list_B = ['D']`

So  `df[df.index.isin(list_A)]` yields:

```
     one   two three

A    ...   ...   ... 
B    ...   ...   ... 
F    ...   ...   ...
```

What I want is `df[df.index.isin(['A','B','D','F'])]` WITHOUT combining the lists:

```
     one   two three

A    ...   ...   ... 
B    ...   ...   ... 
D    ...   ...   ... 
F    ...   ...   ...
```

But when I try '`df[df.index.isin(list_A or List_B)]` or  and `df[df.index.isin(list_A) or df.index.isin(list_B)]` it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df[(df.index.isin(list_A)) & (df.index.isin(list_B))]` will work without combining list.

Comment: Yep.  That did it!  Thanks.

Comment: You just had `df[(df.index.isin(list_A + listB)) ` which worked.  That seems to keep the lists distict but doesn't combine them.

Comment: I thought you said no combining lists lol.. and `+` combines it (in memory)

Comment: @RockyLi, You need `|` (not `&`) for a vectorised or condition.

Comment: @jpp oops mistake.

Comment: @RockyLi  `list_A + list_B` combines in memory but `list_ A` and `list_B` remain distinct, no?  If not I need to go with your alternative.

Comment: Yes. you're correct. I was just thinking there are some arbitrary limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

#### Use `|` (bitwise "or") with two series

`df.index.isin(lst)` gives a Boolean series, so use a vectorised `or` operation via `|`:

```
df_filtered = df[df.index.isin(list_A) | df.index.isin(list_B)]
```

#### Combine lists before using `pd.Index.isin`

Potentially more efficiently, index via a single Boolean series accounting for both input lists:

```
df_filtered = df[df.index.isin(list_A + list_B)]
```

Comment: I tried `df_filtered = df[df.index.isin(list_A) | df.index.isin(list_B)]`but with `or` instead of `|`.  Why would that happen?  I've had issues from time to time where the syntax demands `and` or `or` instead of `&` or `|`

Comment: @Windstorm1981, As explained, don't use `or` / `and` for vectorised operations.  Use `|` and `&` respectively. Why? Because these series aren't Boolean values they are array-like.